# How to Pass array variable to laravel providers directive

Tags: php, laravel

I want to pass array variable from blade template to providers directive function. Array variable is created in controller.

controller code

```php
$fields = array(
    0 => array(
        'row' => '',
        'elementArray' => array(
            'formType' => array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => '', 'name' => 'formType'),
            'id' => array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => '', 'name' => 'id')
        )
    )
);

return view('welcome',compact('fields'));
```

Blade file code:

```
@createNewForm($fields)
```

Directive function

```php
Blade::directive('createNewForm', function ($fields=array()) {
    return $this->createform($fields);
});
```

Output shows: **it shows variable as string only not shows the full value of the variable** `$fields`

What will be the solution?

Comment: In AppServiceProvider.php    View::share('welcome', $fields);

Answer (score 0):

Just try this 
You are building a macro in blade. You need to return a string

```
Blade::directive('createNewForm', function ($this, $fields = array()) {
    return "<?php $this->createform($fields); ?>";
});
```

Comment: Hello, I just try with same as you updated... but its get Error: ErrorException Undefined property: App\Providers\GlobalProvider::$createform

Comment: I updated my answer and send `$this` as a parameter to the `function()` , check it out and test it